lasy fonts on plain TeX
Is there an already precooked solution so that can I add lasy font symbols on Plain TeX documents? I browsed the CTAN catalogue to no avail.

This is a slightly strange request, the font is deprecated in favour of ams fonts even in latex, but


\newfam\lasy
\font\lasyten = lasy10
\font\lasyseven = lasy7
\font\lasyfive = lasy5
\textfont\lasy = \lasyten
\scriptfont\lasy = \lasyseven
\scriptscriptfont\lasy = \lasyfive

% \the\lasy only works as \lasy is less than 10,
% otherwise you would need an \ifcase\lasy
% to get hex digit

\mathchardef\mho     "0\the\lasy 30
\mathchardef\Join    "3\the\lasy 31
\mathchardef\Box     "0\the\lasy 32
\mathchardef\Diamond "0\the\lasy 33
\mathchardef\leadsto "3\the\lasy 3B
\mathchardef\sqsubset"3\the\lasy 3C
\mathchardef\sqsupset"3\the\lasy 3D
\mathchardef\lhd     "2\the\lasy 01
\mathchardef\unlhd   "2\the\lasy 02
\mathchardef\rhd     "2\the\lasy 03
\mathchardef\unrhd   "2\the\lasy 04

$ x + \mho + \Join $

\bye


neat! but then, what are the tiny pointing wedges in the range '05x?

@jarnosz oh I just translated the latex support which I don't think uses those at all, but the font source has comments about each slot /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/latex-fonts/lasy.mf

those are, according to the comments in the source, the arrowheads for \leadsto, among other things perhaps...

@jarnowicz perhaps once but latexsym (since at least latex2e was released) has \DeclareMathSymbol\leadsto {\mathrel}{lasy}{"3B}  so uses hex 3B octal 73
